# Can I change desktop notification's icon?

Tags: javascript

In firefox it is a megaphone icon while in chrome it's empty.
Is there any way to set my own icon to this notifications?

An example (on Windows):

[image: chrome notification]

Comment: I think most of us have no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: you want a custom icon when your webpage notifies the user of something?  or you want to change the icon of the program when it notifies you of things in general? One of these is not programming related, the other needs a lot more context.

Comment: I added screenshot of what I mean

Comment: When does that appear? It kind of looks like an ``alert`` but not quite.

Comment: If you add relevant code it would property help, OP is talking about the notification api: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> options *Optional*
>   An object that allows to configure the notification. It can have the following properties:
>   **dir**: The direction of the notification; it can be *auto*, *ltr*, or *rtl*
>   **lang**: Specify the lang used within the notification. This string must be a valid BCP 47 language tag.
>   **body**: A string representing an extra content to display within the notification
>   **tag**: An ID for a given notification that allows to retrieve, replace or remove it if necessary
>   **icon**: The URL of an image to be used as an icon by the notification

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification

Usuage:

```
Notification.requestPermission(function(permission ) {
  if (permission === "granted") {
    var notification = new Notification('title', {
      body: 'my body',
      icon: 'http://fc06.deviantart.net/fs70/f/2012/099/d/f/stackoverflow_16x16_icon_by_muntoo_stock-d4vl2v4.png'
    });
  }
});
```